# Low cost way to host a large table yet keep the performance scalable?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, database-design, bigdata

I have a growing table storing time series data, 500M entries now, and 200K new records every day. The total size is around 15GB for now.

My clients are querying the table via a PHP script mostly, and the size of the result set is around 10K records (not very large).

```
select * from T where timestamp > X and timestamp < Y and additionFilters
```

And I want this operation cheap.

Currently my table is hosting in Postgres 7, on a single 16G memory Box, and I would love to see some good suggestion for me to host this in low cost and also allow me to scale up for performance if needed.
The table serves:
 1. Query: 90%
 2. Insert: 9.9%
 2. Update: 0.1% <-- very rare.

Comment: you could write a book on the subject still  it would not answer all the question. you did not tell us about infrastructure ( cluster ? what computer ? caching strategy ? memcache ? h scaling ? v scalling? ect...

Comment: I understand this may sound general, since the solution currently is simple and I am open for suggestion .

Comment: "Postgres 7"?  As in PostgreSQL version 7.x?  The 7.x series is 7-12 years old!  At any rate, this is a classic use case for range partitioning by date http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: If you really are on PostgreSQL 7.something, you *really* need to upgrade.  Really.

Comment: Show us the execution plan, and which indexes you have defined on the table. Oh, and upgrade ***now***. PostgreSQL **7** is so totally outdated. And 9.2 will be a **lot** faster than anything you could achieve even with the best tuning on version 7.

Comment: Your data is 15GB and you have 16GB ram. My guess is that your perf will fall of a steep cliff once you exceed available ram. Fall by 10x or 100x, depending on how much locality of reference there is.

Comment: Come back after you upgraded to a sane [PostgreSQL version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). It's pointless to talk about optimizing a lost case (version 7).

Comment: Do we really need 5 different people to point out what's already been said? Yes, upgrading is certainly a wonderful suggestion but does it sounds better when you say it 5 times?  Please use the upvote to tell us you agree.  He also sounds like he may be shopping around for another solution?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.2 supports partitioning and partial indexes. If there are a few hot partitions, and you can put those partitions or their indexes on a solid state disk, you should be able to run rings around your current configuration.

There may or may not be a low cost, scalable option. It depends on what *low cost* and *scalable* mean to you.